# Preview of an widget setting in a modal

Tags: gui-design, interface, modal

I got this problem with setting up the modal for a widget preview. 
Lets say I want to edit a widget and Im opening modal with the widget settings. 
The problem is, the preview makes the whole modal to high, so the buttons for save/preview disappears outside the screen.. so each time I want to save/preview I need to scroll the modal.

I made this preview: http://1rut2e.axshare.com/#g=1

[image]

On the left side you can see the modal during the configuration of the widget options (the user must click on preview). The second version shows the modal window when the user clicks the preview button: this causes the entire modal to expand and the **save** button sometimes disappears from the screen. Another version of this modal is on the right with the **Save / Preview** buttons located below the widget options, which will be visible during the preview of a widget, and the user can still press **Save** without scrolling

Do you think that the best solution would be to move the buttons **Save / Preview** over the preview area, so that the user has control all the time and just scroll if she wants to see the full preview?

Any response is welcome!

Comment: This forum works best when you bring some visuals that show your efforts and constraints. Do you have a mock of this so far? How much data? If there's other helpful details, it would be helpful to add those as well to your question.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide any mockup for this one. Basically the main issue is - should I display save/preview button below or under the preview area. Displaying preview makes the save/preview buttons jump up-down and usually disappear below the fold.

Comment: Really hard to contextualise this without some example mockup. It doesn't have to be of the actual functionality, just a sketch or something would really help.

Comment: @JohnW OK, I made this preview: https://1rut2e.axshare.com/#g=1. on the left side you can see the modal during setting widget options (the user needs to click preview). The second version shows modal when user clicks preview button - It makes the whole modal window expanding and the button for Saving sometimes disappear from the screen. Another version of this modal is on the right with the buttons for Save/preview located below to the widget options it will be visible during preview of a widget, and user still will be able to press Save without scrolling a modal.

Comment: @JonW can you please unblock this subject?

Answer (score 0):

I think the images are a little misleading as the first does not contain enough content to fill but still extends below the fold.

If shown properly, the first dialog will end after the [Preview] and [Save] buttons and above the fold. Pressing [Preview] will add content, extend the dialog pane to extend below the fold, and probably also add a scrollbar to the side.

Shouldn't this be enough indication to the user that there is more to expect below the fold?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in this case is to make the modal smaller.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/54796)

Comment: I'll amend my answer